How to handle API rate limits in React when fetching?
Title: How to handle API rate limits in JavaScript when fetching quiz questions?
Question:
I'm working on a quiz application that fetches questions from the Open Trivia Database API. The API has a rate limit of 5 seconds, and I'm getting errors when calling the API multiple times consecutively.
Here is the code I'm using:
export const fetchQuizQuestions = async (
  category: string,
  difficulty: string
): Promise<Question[]> => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=${category}&difficulty=${difficulty}&type=multiple`
    );
    const data = await response.json();

    if (data.response_code === 0) {
      return data.results as Question[]; // Cast results to Question[]
    } else {
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch questions');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching quiz questions:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};

Problem: When I call this function multiple times in quick succession, I keep getting errors due to the API's 5-second rate limit. , i don't wanna have errors in my console =D
Question: How can I modify my code to handle the rate limit and avoid getting errors when making consecutive API calls? What strategies or patterns should I use to ensure that I don't exceed the rate limit?

You probably shouldn't try to avoid getting errors, instead just handle them properly. In this case by waiting a little and resending the request. If the response gives you details on how long you need to wait, use that. If not, I would use a standard exponential backoff.

the Api documentation has this Code 5: Rate Limit Too many requests have occurred. Each IP can only access the API once every 5 seconds.
i want to fix the probléme and avoid getting errors

And I told you how to do that. Just wait and then resend the request.

My solution checks whether 5 seconds have passed since the last request, and waits if not, in order to avoid exceeding the request limit.
You can also implement a queue that gathers/stores all the requests to be sent/are sending, and only resolves when the last request has finished. Then, create a logical operator to check if 5 seconds have passed from timestamp returned by the fetch function.
let lastRequestTime = 0;

export const fetchQuizQuestions = async (
    category: string,
    difficulty: string
): Promise<Question[]> => {
    const currentTime = Date.now();

    if (currentTime - lastRequestTime < 5000) {
        const timeToWait = 5000 - (currentTime - lastRequestTime);
        console.log(`Wait ${timeToWait / 1000} seconds before next request...`);
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, timeToWait)); // Creates async friendly timeout.
    }

    lastRequestTime = Date.now();

    const response = await fetch(
        `https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=${category}&difficulty=${difficulty}&type=multiple`
    );
    const data = await response.json();

    if (data.response_code === 0) {
        return data.results as Question[];
    } else {
        throw new Error("Failed to fetch questions");
    }
};

